# How to Connect Buttons with TextInput of QML using PySide

Tags: qt, qml, pyside

I try to learn PySide-QML connections and try to make a simple application like addition. Such as: a+b=c. How can I connect the button to calculate two inputs?
Thanks

Edit: My code's algorithm: when pressing button, it just types 10. When clicking somewhere in the window, it types "hello man" on interpreter.

Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import math
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtDeclarative import *

class MainWindow(QDeclarativeView):
    now=Signal(str)
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Main Widnowww")
        self.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile('view.qml'))
        self.setResizeMode(QDeclarativeView.SizeRootObjectToView)
        #self.rootObject().messageRequired.connect(self.echo)
        self.rootObject().messageRequired.connect(self.emit_now)
        self.rootObject().clicked.connect(self.printThat)
        self.now.connect(self.rootObject().updateMessage)
    def printThat(self):
        print "hello man"
        #print str(bt)
    def emit_now(self):
        a=6
        b=4
        c=a+b
        #formatted_date = v.toString()
        formatted_date = str(c)
        self.now.emit(formatted_date)
    def echo(self,a_text,b_text):
        an=float(a_text or 0)
        bn=float(b_text or 0)
        ce=an + bn
        c=str(ce)
        self.rootObject().updateAnswer(str(c))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    window=MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

QML code:

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Rectangle {
    id: rectangle1
    width: 480
    height: 272



    gradient: Gradient {
        GradientStop {
            id: gradientStop1
            position: 0
            color: "#ffffff"
        }

        GradientStop {
            position: 1
            color: "#abc09f"
        }
    }

    function updateScoreA(string ) {
        score_a.text = string
    }

    function updateScoreB(string ) {
        score_b.text = string
    }

    Text {
        id: score_a
        x: 45
        y: 8
        width: 131
        height: 48
        text: qsTr("Text")
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        font.pixelSize: 12
    }

    Text {
        id: score_b
        x: 303
        y: 8
        width: 131
        height: 48
        text: qsTr("Text")
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
        font.pixelSize: 12
    }
    Text {
        id: dash
        x: 232
        y: 5
        text: qsTr("-")
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        font.pixelSize: 47
    }
    MouseArea {
        id: a_scored
        x: 303
        y: 200
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: team_a
        x: 45
        y: 218
        width: 127
        height: 46
        color: "#4e3a3a"
        radius: 10
        TextInput {
            id: team_a_txt
            x: 24
            y: 13
            width: 80
            height: 20
            text: qsTr("A")
            horizontalAlignment: TextInput.AlignHCenter
            font.pixelSize: 12
        }
        MouseArea {
            id: team_a_score_ma
            x: 0
            y: 0
            width: 126
            height: 46
            onClicked: {
                qScoreInterface.aScored()
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: team_b
        x: 307
        y: 218
        width: 127
        height: 46
        color: "#4e3a3a"
        radius: 10
        TextInput {
            id: team_b_txt
            x: 24
            y: 13
            width: 80
            height: 20
            text: qsTr("B")
            horizontalAlignment: TextInput.AlignHCenter
            font.pixelSize: 12
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: team_b_score_ma
            x: 0
            y: 0
            width: 126
            height: 46
            onClicked: {
                qScoreInterface.bScored()
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: startstopgame
        x: 177
        y: 113
        width: 127
        height: 46
        color: "#4e3a3a"
        radius: 10
        TextInput {
            id: startstopgame_txt
            x: 24
            y: 13
            width: 80
            height: 20
            text: qsTr("Start Game")
            horizontalAlignment: TextInput.AlignHCenter
            font.pixelSize: 12
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: startstopgame_ma
            x: 1
            y: 0
            width: 126
            height: 46
            onClicked: {
                qScoreInterface.startMatch()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the relevant code to Stack Overflow?

Comment: I think links of my codes are the relevant. Stack Overflow did not accept codes because they are too long. Anyone may compile my qt-python codes when they install required libraries.

Comment: After my code had been edited by admins, I cannot compile python code with qml file. I did not know I cannot give a link (like pastebin) for codes.